# Error 28 when sending SMS to short numbers

Tags: sms

I am using Android 6.0 and when I try to send SMS (via Hangouts or Messenger) to a 4-digit number, I get a confirmation pop-up and then an error saying

> Can't send message with `SIM_NAME`, error 28

I've tried to clear cache. Messages to regular numbers can be sent without any problems.

Why, and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

There's a possibility that **the short number/code hasn't been registered by the operator**.

There are 2 similar cases happen with different operator:

- [Sky Mobile](https://helpforum.sky.com/t5/Sky-Mobile/SMS-error-28/m-p/2988899/highlight/true#M15289)

  > Why won't my phone allow me to send an SMS to a 5 digit number? It keeps telling me error 28 try again. I only activated my SIM card on Saturday.
  >
  > ---
  >
  > Not all, if any, short codes are supported on Sky Mobile I’m afraid
- [ID mobile](https://community.idmobile.co.uk/ask-a-question-18/sms-short-code-error-28-29203)

  > I enter a few text competitions a month that use short codes, usually ITV competitions or the Gadget Show. However the new Gadget Show competition that uses short code 65555 will not send and I simply get a popup error of: Cannot send message with id - error 28
  >
  > Everything else works, phone, internet, texting. I even entered another competition that uses a short code beginning 6 and that works fine. I still have loads of unused credit before I reach my cap.
  >
  > Gadget show comp has changed the SMS number this series and I read somewhere that short codes have to be manually registered with the network providers to work, so maybe ID have not enabled 65555 yet??
  >
  > ---
  >
  > Hi all, we've got the problem sorted that was preventing you sending a message to 65555.

If that's the case, then there's really nothing that can be done from the user's side except by letting their operator know and request to allow/register the short numbers. Otherwise, switching to a different operator is the last alternative.

Answer (score 0):

U need to allow sending premium messages. Go to settings,apps,messages,permissions,premium messages,always allow

Comment: I see no premium messages permission.